# How is an EEPROM different from a Flash memory?

Tags: memory, flash, eeprom, non-volatile-memory, rom

I am trying to understand the terminology used for various non-volatile memory chips for example as [EEPROM](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/doc5194.pdf) and [Flash](https://www.winbond.com/resource-files/w25q256jv%20spi%20revb%2009202016.pdf).

[image: EEPROM Features]
[image: Flash Features]

Is there any preference to use the word EEPROM or Flash for specific type of memory chips or is it some specific technology difference in the two types?

Comment: here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/69234/what-is-the-difference-between-flash-memory-and-eeprom

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory ? Quote: *Although flash memory is technically a type of EEPROM, the term "EEPROM" is generally used to refer specifically to non-flash EEPROM which is erasable in small blocks*.

Comment: @alt-rose Stack exchange sites are reserved only for the questions which remains *after* doing basic research.  Much as with your recent Cortex R question you could have easily found your own answer to this, in this case already right here on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An EEPROM can be erased per address and has higher write endurance. Flash must be erased per page but has higher density.

Comment: Does it mean that the digital circuit in both is fundamentally same specially the cell in which a 'bit' of data is stored but the way cells are grouped together for read or write or erase operations they are different in these two memory types?

Comment: @alt-rose No. they are different technologies with different design choices made. not just rehashes of each other. I'm just telling you the practical differences. BTW specially and especially mean different things.

Comment: Do these memory types use 'MOSFET Gate Capacitors' as their basic storage cells for storing the binary 1's and 0's data or is it some other technology?

Comment: @alt-rose MOSFET gate capacitors are DRAM that needs refreshing and loses its memory when power is lost. So no.

Comment: Ok. Can you tell what is the basic construction of a cell in Flash or EEPROM memories?

Comment: @alt-rose Why don't you search for it online? It's everywhere out there. Even the wikipedia entries tells you.